# Custom Authentication Filters in multiple HttpSecurity objects using Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to have two different http web configurations with custom authentication filters using spring boot and spring java config. 
I followed the sample application that can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/samples-web.md#sample-multi-http-web-configuration.
My understanding was, that this would end up in a separate spring filter chain for each of the web configurations. But both filters are invoked although the web configuration url pattern doesn't match the request. 
For instance, requesting http://localhost:8080/api/dosomething will invoke both filters, not only CustomApiAuthenticationFilter. Of course, it would be possible to check the request url in doFilterInternal and ignore the request if it doesn't match but I thought this should be done automatically by respecting the url pattern of the corresponding web configuration.
Furthermore, my RestController doesn't get called respectively Postman only receives Status Code 200 OK with no response body.

Two questions:
1. Is this behaviour by design or is the configuration wrong?
2. Why is my RestController not invoked?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public GenericFilterBean apiAuthenticationFilter() {
            return new CustomApiAuthenticationFilter();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.antMatcher("/api/**").addFilterAfter(apiAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public GenericFilterBean webAuthenticationFilter() {
            return new CustomWebAuthenticationFilter();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/").addFilterAfter(webAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").authenticated();
        }
    }
}

public class CustomApiAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("sub", "password", ImmutableList.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("API")));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    }
}

public class CustomWebAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("sub", "password", ImmutableList.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    }
}

@RestController
public class ApiController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/dosomething", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSomething() {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your filter is a bean. Spring Boot detects those and adds them to the regular filter chain and not only the Spring Security filter chain. So they will probably be even invoked twice instead of once.

Comment: Well as you extend `OncePerRequestFilter` they will be invoked just once but the issue is that the filter is detect as a plain `javax.servlet.Filter` and as such added as a regular filter as well. Hence the execution

Comment: Okay, after removing the `@Bean` annotation, only the correct filter is invoked. But I still have the problem that my `RestController` doesn't get called. Any ideas?

Comment: In `doFilterInternal`, I can manually forward the request via `request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getRequestURI()).forward(request, response);` after successful authentication but this approach looks wrong to me, right?

Comment: It is actually your `doFilterInternal` method that is breaking stuff. It stops processing at your filter. In your method you have to call the filter chain to keep processing else the request stops right there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, totally overlooked that. After adding `filterChain.doFilter(request, response)` everything works as expected. Is this approach generally disregarded because I'm bypassing the `AuthenticationManager` / `AuthenticationProvider` / `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` approach?

Comment: Whats the use of the filter or security in general. You are always adding a hardcoded username/password so anyone accessing the URL will be able to enter. So basically you have disabled security (at least that is how I see it).

Comment: The filter implementation was just for testing purposes. Of course, the filters and how I derive the authentication object will use a different algorithm in production :). What I meant was the general idea of how I'm using the filters in combination with authentication and spring security.

Comment: I would probably extend the `AbstractPreAuthenticationFilter` instead of what you have now. As that is what you basically try to do, use some pre established credentials (from whatever source) to authenticate the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I will also go for the  `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` approach then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my previous answer, it is also possible to keep the `@Bean` annotation by creating corresponding spring `FilterRegistrationBean` manually and disabling automatic filter registration. This will also preserve autowiring in the filters.

```
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean customApiAuthenticationFilterRegistration() {
            FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(customApiAuthenticationFilter());
            registration.setEnabled(false);
            return registration;
        }

        @Bean
        public GenericFilterBean customApiAuthenticationFilter() {
            return new CustomApiAuthenticationFilter();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/**").addFilterAfter(customApiAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("API").and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean customWebAuthenticationFilterRegistration() {
            FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(customWebAuthenticationFilter());
            registration.setEnabled(false);
            return registration;
        }

        @Bean
        public GenericFilterBean customWebAuthenticationFilter() {
            return new CustomWebAuthenticationFilter();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/").addFilterAfter(customWebAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to M. Deinum who gave me the right answer. The following now works as expected but still I'm not sure if this is a legitimate approach.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .addFilterAfter(new CustomApiAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("API");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/")
                .addFilterAfter(new CustomWebAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
        }
    }
}

public class CustomApiAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("sub", "password", ImmutableList.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_API")));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

public class CustomWebAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("sub", "password", ImmutableList.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```